# object storage in git

Tags: database, git, blob, berkeley-db

Doing stuff like "git ls-files" on big repos I have noticed that git is quite fast in this regard, subjectively faster than "find . -type f" would be I think (although I haven't done benchmarks).

Is git using some sort of binary key-value data store internally for storing blobs/deltas, like berkeley db or tokyo cabinet?

Comment: anyway, I think you can get lots of help with some searches. e.g., checkout this: http://www.gitguys.com/topics/the-git-object-model-starting-with-the-blob/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes Git is basically a key-value store. A more technical name would be a **content-addressable** file system. Any kind of data stored within git can be retrieved using a key, which is a **SHA-1 hash**. There is a whole section on [git objects in the git book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-Git-Objects)